# How to get internal matching result of Java's Matcher.replaceAll?

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I need to replace some parts of a string which may or may not be available and in Perl `s///` returns the number of replacements made. This can easily be used to answer the question if anything has been replaced at all. I'm trying to do the same in Java using `Matcher.replaceAll` and while that seems to have the [matching result internally](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#L902), I don't see any way to access it. This would leave me with either comparing the returned and input string for differences or matching the regular expression myself first and use `replaceAll` afterwards as needed only, which seems to then match the string again.

Or am I missing something and there is some state/flag that can be queried?

Comment: When the input is a `String` (rather than another `CharSequence` implementation) and there were no matches, the resulting string will be the same object as the original string, so a reference comparison is sufficient to recognize this. Note that this is different to the case where there were matches, but the replacement strings yield a result equal to the original text.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 9 the Matcher class provides a method called results() which returns a Stream. You could do something like :

```
int count = matcher.results().count();
```

Comment: Thank G-d they finally made it easier +1.

Comment: But if you only want to find out whether there were any matches, you don’t have to count all of them, so `matcher.results().findAny().isPresent()` or `matcher.results().anyMatch(x -> true)` would be sufficient, though it’s not different to just calling `matcher.find()` once, which works even before Java 9.

Comment: I'm not yet, but your answer implies a "no" for all older versions of Java and provides the thing I was looking for in the end, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning either, you have a misunderstanding of what this solution does or you need a better definition of your actual requirement. The statement `int count = matcher.results().count();` is not better than `int count = 0; while(matcher.find()) count++;` which works since Java 1.4.

Comment: You're right, I've misunderstood the docs, but the implementation is additionally calling `find`, which is NOT what I was interested in. I thought it simply returns internally collected state of `find` executed during `replaceAll` already. This is what I'm interested in, the internal state of the matcher after `replaceAll`. https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk9/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#L1326

Answer (score 2):

You may use a pattern matcher and just keep count of the matches.  The code below is sort of the slow motion, more controllable, way of doing a regex replacement.  As an example, I assume that you want to replace all occurrences of `dog` with `cat`.

```
String line = "There was a big dog, larger than the other dog.";
String pattern = "\\bdog\\b";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

int count = 0;
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buff, "cat");
    ++count;
}

m.appendTail(buff);
System.out.println(buff.toString());
System.out.println("There were " + count + " matches.");
```

**Output:**

```
There was a big cat, larger than the other cat.
There were 2 matches.
```

Note that there is a clever, much simpler solution than the above, which you hinted at.  We could compare the length of the string before and after the regex replacement.  But, we could not use this method for the example I gave, because the starting and replacement strings happen to be the same length.

Comment: Why “slow motion”? This is *exactly* what the convenience method `replaceAll` does under the hood. The only difference is that it will do a first `find()` before the `StringBuilder` allocation, to return the original string when there is not even a single match and hence, the loop will be a `do … while` then. Due to this optimization, you can use a reference comparison to find out whether there were any matches, so even when the replacements evaluate exactly to the same result string contents as the original string, it will be a new string. But your solution has almost the same performance.

Comment: @Holger I was referring to the fact that my code sort of spells out what `String#replaceAll` does under the hood.  Anyway, the accepted answer's one liner is better, I think, unless we want to both do a replace all _and_ get the count in one go, in which case my answer becomes competitive.

Comment: That’s how I understood it, to do it in one go. As said at the other answer, if that’s not a requirement, a plain `find()` will tell you about the presence of matches, without the need to process a stream of matches. Your solution is what I would do, or, when I know beforehand that there are no group references in the replacement string, I’d use `start()` and `end()` indices of the matches to do repeated `StringBuilder.append(CharSequence,int,int)` which would be even faster.